# rails development environment circular dependency error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, precompile

Last night I think I did something that hosed my rails development environment, and I'm unable to reverse what I did.

I migrated an update to production and was having some trouble precompiling a stylesheet so I backed out the changes and decided to attempt a precompile on my development machine.

Long story short, the precompile failed on my development machine (local) but when I tried to bring up my test system I got this error:

> Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Devise/sessions#new
>
> /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required

I'm certain this has something to do with my attempted precompile, even though it failed because prior to that everything was working fine.

I tried to do precompile:clear because I read somewhere that will reverse/delete the precompile.

Am I missing something here? Does a precompile change configuration files somewhere that I need to manually reset?

This is rails 3.1 running on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because your application.css.scss is most likely requiring a css file that's requiring application.css.scss. You'll want to go through `app/assets/stylesheets` and check the headers of `application.css.scss`, and then the headers of all the files it requires to make sure that none of them reference `application.css.scss`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that's precisely what it was.

Comment: Thanks. I had an `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.orig` in the directory tree. That was causing my problem.

Comment: Ultraedit (my text editor) was creating .bak backup files automatically in the the stylesheets folder which caused the same error. Deleting them (and turning off that feature!) resolved the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating an application.css.scss and by importing each of my files in there, like this:

@import "backend.css.scss";
@import "frontend.css.scss";

then it worked